# display digital clock using ftl

Tags: javascript

I am trying to a display digital clock using ftl. So for this I want use timer and date apis and have to display the time in div tag.

Could any one help me on this.Thanking you in adavnce.

Regards
Narasimha Reddy P

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. what did you try? can we see some code?

Comment: What does the abbreviation, "ftl" stand for? (please don't say Faster than Light) :-)

Comment: I thought FTL was a JIT compiler for javascript that comes with Webkit

Comment: ftl stads for "free maker template language". It is like html and jsp for UI design.